# (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: database "players" does not exist

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

This is a program that I had written a while ago and it had been working fine, but now when I run it I'm getting this error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "players" does not exist

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgres://postgres:%password%@localhost:5432/players'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
```

models

```
class Player(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "players"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
player_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Initially when I ran this program I was getting the following error: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres

Then I found from another post The URI should start with postgresql:// instead of postgres://. SQLAlchemy used to accept both, but has removed support for the postgres name.

I updated that part of the code and now it is giving me the error that the database doesn't exist.

What else am I missing here? I tried using 5433 as well. I'm able to connect to the database through the terminal

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the database is called "players"?  I see the table is called "players".

Comment: Well I feel silly now. Thanks! It's been a while since I was looking at this

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the database players. The database does not exist.